# Spark Scala dataframe columns to nested json

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to convert the dataframe to nested json.

Basically final output is at the field "`id`" level with nested json format of other fields.

Json format using the field "`rank`" as key and "`desc`" and "`percent`" as values. Appreciate your help!

Source Data:-

```
val df = Seq(
  ("1", "ABC", "1","91.68"),
  ("1", "BCD", "2","89.03"),
  ("1", "DEF", "3","78.32"),
  ("1", "XYZ", "4","70.64")
).toDF("id", "desc", "rank", "percent")

+---+----+----+-------+
|id |desc|rank|percent|
+---+----+----+-------+
|1  |ABC |1   |91.68  |
|1  |BCD |2   |89.03  |
|1  |DEF |3   |78.32  |
|1  |XYZ |4   |70.64  |
+---+----+----+-------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |json                                                                                                                                                    |
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{"1":{"desc":"ABC","percent":"91.68"},"2":{"desc":"BCD","percent":"89.03"},"3":{"desc":"DEF","percent":"78.32"},"4":{"desc":"XYZ","percent":"70.64"}}   |
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a simple UDF to fix the json as you need:

```
val toJsonUDF = udf((key: String, jsonString: String) =>  "{ " + key + ":" + jsonString + "}")
```

Then create a json column with the `withColumn` method using the previous UDF and the `to_json` method which creates a jsonString from the given columns:

```
df.withColumn("json", toJsonUDF($"rank", to_json(struct("desc","percent"))))
  .select("id", "json")
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(collect_list("json").as("json"))
```

OUTPUT

```
      +---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      |id |collect_list(json)                                                                                                                                          |
      +---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      |1  |[{ 1:{"desc":"ABC","percent":"91.68"}}, { 2:{"desc":"BCD","percent":"89.03"}}, { 3:{"desc":"DEF","percent":"78.32"}}, { 4:{"desc":"XYZ","percent":"70.64"}}]|
      +---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```