# How to dynamically convert Spark DataFrame to Nested json using Spark Scala

Tags: arrays, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, nested-json

I want to convert the DataFrame to nested JSON.

Source Data:

DataFrame has data values like:
`[you.you1.you3: String, you.you1.me2:decimal ]`

Expected Output:

I have to convert DataFrame value to Json like
`{ "you" : { "you1" :{ "you3" : String,"me2":decimal}}}`

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And especially for Spark questions [How to make good reproducible Apache Spark examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark Scala dataframe columns to nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63858239/spark-scala-dataframe-columns-to-nested-json)